# Issue in galleria.js usage

Tags: javascript, html, galleria

I am trying to implement `galleria.js` in my webpage. I have followed the documentation and have created `index.html` accordingly. All I am getting is the compilation of the images one after another, but not the galleria view.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>my photo</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="galleria/im/out1.jpg">
            <img src="galleria/im/out2.jpg">
            <img src="galleria/im/out3.jpg">
        </div>

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

        <script src="galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#gallery').galleria({
                transition: 'fadeslide',
                width:800,
                height:600
            });
         });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the docs of galleria.js but I think the issue is basically the selector in your code. You are getting an element with id "gallery" and you dont have any element with that id,just an element with that class :)

```
$('#gallery').galleria({
```

ans I think it should be

```
$('.gallery').galleria({
```

Comment: I have revised the codes. The problem I find is in the`jquery` script. Thanks.

Comment: Its ok I think it was a combination of both since your new code shows the selector changed :)

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts the following works fine with me. I have missed to put `https://` before the `jquery` address.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta  charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>my photo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="gallery">
            <img src="galleria/im/out.jpg">
            <img src="galleria/im/out1.jpg">
            <img src="galleria/im/out3.jpg">
        </div>


        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="galleria/galleria-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

        <script src="galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#gallery').galleria({
                transition: 'fadeslide',
                width:1450,
                height:740
            });
         });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```